# AutoSuggest Using PHP/MySQL & Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, autosuggest

So I've created a autosuggest for my search engine similar to google using PHP/MYSQL and Ajax. If my MySQL has 2 different title of the same name how do i get only one of them to appear on autosuggest? For example: I have a field with title= ufc 131 and another with title=ufc 131 . When I search for UFC 131 how i get only one of them to show?

The code i use is..

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    $str = strtolower($_GET['content']);
    if(strlen($str))
    {
        $sel = mysql_query("select * from Streams where title like '".trim($str)."%'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sel))
        {
            echo "<table border =\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n";
            if(mysql_num_rows($sel))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\">box('1');</script>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
                {
                    $country = str_ireplace($str,"<b>".$str."</b>",($row['title']));
                    echo "<tr id=\"word".$row['title']."\" onmouseover=\"highlight(1,'".$row['title']."');\" onmouseout=\"highlight(0,'".$row['title']."');\" onClick=\"display('".$row['title']."');\" >\n<td>".$country."</td>\n</tr>\n";
                }
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">box('0');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: your script is very vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection+php)

Comment: huh? im sorry im new to sql injection

Comment: *never trust user input*. Always escape strings from users before using them in queries, and always escape strings before showing them to the users. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). This is not related to your current problem, just a warning.

Comment: I second this. If a user for example types following 'search string', it will delete the entire search suggestion table.: 

    "'; DELETE * FROM Streams"

So, given how simple this is, imagine what other insanity could happen from this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the DISTINCT function, you can use the GROUP BY function, or you can even put all of your search results in an array in PHP after fetching it from MySQL and then using the array_unique() function to filter out duplicates.

But none of that is as efficient as making sure that the database doesn't contain any duplicates. What I mean to say is that, since you are providing a suggestion, you want the 'SELECT' element to run *as fast as possible*. Any type of trickery, like the ones I listed above, will require a combination of more time, more memory, and  more CPU. Therefore, what you want to do is make sure that the database is in a good condition so that the SELECT statements can be as smooth as possible. A good way to do this is to make the 'title' field in your 'Streams' table a UNIQUE index. However, what I personally have, is a FULLTEXT index on my 'suggestion field'. The UNIQUE index will make sure there won't be any duplicates in the database for sure, but all that does it let you get away with sloppy PHP code for the insert. If you use proper FULLTEXT search, you can do FULLTEXT searches (MATCH() AGAINST()). Since those searches uses the index, they are performed MUCH faster. Your query statement will with no type of index actually use the index.

On top of that, you probably also want to update your PHP (/ echo) code some bit, cause, though your code is really small, it is not written optimally (which again, is something you WANT to make sure, in the case of search suggestions).

Comment: can u do the code for me as i have no idea ? i just want to filter out duplicates

Comment: @Mdkd: Sure I can do the code for you, but like I said, you should not want to make this bug go away from THIS side of your system. Though it is possible, I STRONGLY suggest you to keep the code on the <i>SELECT</i> end of the query as simple as possible. You want to make sure that the information is <i>put in</i> correctly. For me to help you with that code, I need to see what your code looks like from that point of view.

Answer (score 0):

your code needs to be revamped.
A good way for making autosuggestion is to use the minimum amount of data possible.
So in this case you can use [JSON](http://json.org/example.html).

```
include('conn.php');
$str = strtolower($_GET['content']);
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str); // escape to prevent sql injection
```

Now for your query, You can use the GROUP BY keyword in mysql to not have duplicate lines

```
$sel = "SELECT title FROM Streams
        WHERE title LIKE '{$str}%'
        GROUP BY title 
        LIMIT 10";
```

Now for the returned data you can return it in Javascript object notation JSON

```
$data = "{";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
   $data .= '"title":"'.$row['title'].'",';
}
$data .= "}";
```

now you can echo the content

```
echo $data;
```

In your javascript you can use a library like [Jquery](http://jquery.net) to make it easy to retrieve the lightweight json data

I hope this helps you make a very good autosuggestion box

Comment: Other than my objections to the DISTINCT function for this system (read my answer), I agree with Ibu that JSON data is much more efficient in this scenario. However, I would suggest not to write the code this way, but instead to rawurlencode() the $row['title'] (and then unescape() in JS) and put it in an array. Then use the php function json_encode() before sending it off (and then use JSON.parse() in JS). This will give you much better performance in many ways.

Comment: the code that you put for the query gives me this error Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /vhosts/firemoon.me/httpdocs/script_page.php on line 9